# How to add/print in cucumber report in karate reponse.

Tags: karate

I want to add request and response in cucumber report. If i use print statement, it prints in console, not in the cucumber html report. How can i add this in the report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print request and response details in your report, you can set the logger level to `DEBUG` in logback-test.xml

```
<logger name="com.intuit" level="DEBUG" />
```

Comment: its printing in log file, not in the cucumber html report

Comment: which version of karate are you using? you can raise a issue here https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: i am using 0.6.2

Comment: problem is in our current set up i can not use latest than 0.6.2

Comment: is there any solution in 0.6.2?

Comment: @Karate Coder I tried a sample code with 0.6.2 and its printing the request and response on the cucumber reports as expected. If you are still facing this issue please follow this for further help -> https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a bit too late but for the benefit of others who may refer to this

`* configure report = { showLog: true, showAllSteps: false }`

Include this in the feature file and this should do what you want